# Xamarin Studio iOS UI Designer without Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've read about new [iOS UI Designer](http://blog.xamarin.com/hands-on-xamarin-studio%E2%80%99s-powerful-new-ios-designer/) lately built into Xamarin Studio.

Is there a way to use it for non-storyboard applications?

P.S. It's better to be ask on Xamarin blog itself, but it seems there are no comments there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin have currently said this will be only for Storyboards.

You might be able to influence them through voting on a new issue or on an existing one like:

- http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-suggestions/suggestions/2700302-a-monotouch-xib-editor
- http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-suggestions/suggestions/3589990-give-monodevelop-a-designer-editor-for-monotouch-a